# password authentication failed for user postgres using docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to make requests from a node bash to a node backend with a database, so first I up this docker-compose:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  backend:
    build: .
    ports:
       - '2000:2000'
  db:
    image: 'postgres'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '12345'
      POSTGRES_DB: 'attendancebd'
```

It works well. I just create a bash in node and when I make a curl like:

```
curl backend:2000/info/teachers
```

it gives me the correct JSON that I have in the db.

But when I use this docker compose:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    networks:
      serveranddb:
        aliases:
          - server_host
      serverandbash:
        aliases:
          - server_host          
  db:
    image: 'postgres'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '12345'
      POSTGRES_DB: 'attendancebd'
    networks:
      serveranddb:
        aliases:
          - db_host          
  mybash:
    build: ./bash
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    networks:
      serverandbash:
        aliases:
          - bash_host    
networks:
  serveranddb:
    name: server_db
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
  serverandbash:
    name: server_bash
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
```

And I do the same curl from bash:

```
curl server_host:2000/info/teachers
```

it sends me the message:

```
{"message":"password authentication failed for user \"postgres\""}
```

And the environment is the same, with the same password and same database, why this is happening?

Comment: Look in the database servers log file

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, i have to put a depends_on into the server service so it will wait the db for raise up:

```
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    networks:
      serveranddb:
        aliases:
          - server_host
      serverandbash:
        aliases:
          - server_host
    depends_on:
      - db
```